# opentk vb.net multiple rotations and translation

Tags: vb.net, opentk

I'm writing a small sfw with vb.net and OpenTK actually I can load and render some stl files correctly.

The purpose of my program is to show a CNC machine and reading the gcode file to show the simulation of file.

I have a problem with rotation of parts, some parts must be rotated and tranlated few times example 45° on Z axis and 50° on X axis and after translate on XYZ

I have try like this:

```
For Each p As Pezzo In ListaPezzi   'Draw all peaces

    GL.PushMatrix()                                 'Fix actually situation
    GL.Translate(p.DeX, p.DeY, p.DeZ)               'Translation on peace reference
    GL.Rotate(p.AlfaX, 1, 0, 0)                     'Rotation X
    GL.Rotate(p.AlfaY, 0, 1, 0)                     'Rotation Y
    GL.Rotate(p.AlfaZ, 0, 0, 1)                     'Rotation Z
    GL.Translate(-p.DeX, -p.DeY, -p.DeZ)            'Restore peace position

    If p.Tipo = Pezzo.Type.STL Then DisegnaSTL(p)   'Draw peace

    GL.PopMatrix()                                  'return matrix to past state

Next
```

After the first rotation the other rotations are "projected" on the first rotation.

Comment: I think you're going to need to explain this a whole heap more.  What exactly is the problem?  I'm assuming your getting some unexpected results, what are they and what should they be.  What is the GL & P objects.  Throwing a whole lot of task specific  terms in your question confuses your question.  For example, is gcode file relevant, what's it for.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to set the point of view and the drawing system:

```
Imports OpenTK
Imports OpenTK.Graphics
Imports OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class Form1

Private Sub GlControl1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles GlControl1.Paint

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit)
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)


    Vista.Proporzioni = GlControl1.Width / GlControl1.Height

    Dim perspective As Matrix4
    perspective = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(Vista.Xmin, Vista.Xmin + Vista.Size, Vista.Ymin, Vista.Ymin + (Vista.Size / Vista.Proporzioni), Vista.ProfMin, Vista.ProfMax)


    'Perspective
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection) 'load the camera
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.LoadMatrix(perspective)


    GL.Viewport(0, 0, GlControl1.Width, GlControl1.Height)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
    GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less)


    GL.Rotate(Vista.AngoloX, New Vector3(1, 0, 0)) 'asse X
    GL.Rotate(0, New Vector3(0, 1, 0)) 'asse Y
    GL.Rotate(Vista.AngoloZ, New Vector3(0, 0, 1)) 'asse Z



    DisegnaOrg()
    DisegnaGriglia()
    DisegnaPezzi()


    'Finally..................
    GraphicsContext.CurrentContext.VSync = True ' to syncronize with the GPU ability
    GlControl1.SwapBuffers() 'takes from GL and put to control
    GlControl1.Invalidate()


End Sub
```

When I load my stl without transformation with code:

```
DisegnaSTL(p)   'Draw peace
```

DisegnaSTL simpy do:

```
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles)
    GL.Color3(Color.Silver)
    GL.Vertex3(_p1.X, _p1.Y, _p1.Z)
    GL.Vertex3(_p2.X, _p2.Y, _p2.Z)
    GL.Vertex3(_p3.X, _p3.Y, _p3.Z)
    GL.End()
```

for every triangle of stl

the system load like this:
[loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AERkF.png)

Now for me is necessary to rotate on X axis then on Z axis then move peace on final position, example 45° in X, 90° in Z and then move in x=20 y=30 z=10

If I apply only X rotation like this:

```
GL.PushMatrix()                                 'Fix actually situation
GL.Rotate(-45, 1, 0, 0)                     'Rotation X
DisegnaSTL(p)   'Draw peace
GL.PopMatrix()                                  'return matrix to past state
```

the result is correct:
[only x rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khh9u.png)

If I apply only Z rotation like this:

```
GL.PushMatrix()                                 'Fix actually situation
GL.Rotate(90, 0, 0, 1)                     'Rotation Z
DisegnaSTL(p)   'Draw peace
GL.PopMatrix()                                  'return matrix to past state
```

the result is correct:
[only z rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUstr.png)

If I apply X and Z rotation like this:

```
GL.PushMatrix()                                 'Fix actually situation
GL.Rotate(-45, 1, 0, 0)                     'Rotation X
GL.Rotate(90, 0, 0, 1)                     'Rotation Z
DisegnaSTL(p)   'Draw peace
GL.PopMatrix()                                  'return matrix to past state
```

the result is not correct:
[xz rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujRUW.png)

Then if I apply the translation also that is not correct, I try to apply just 10 in Y direction with this code:

```
        GL.PushMatrix()                                 'Fix actually situation
        GL.Rotate(-45, 1, 0, 0)                     'Rotation X
        GL.Rotate(90, 0, 0, 1)                     'Rotation Z
        GL.Translate(-0, 10, -0)               'Translation 
        DisegnaSTL(p)   'Draw peace
        GL.PopMatrix()                                  'return matrix to past state
```

and the result is:
[final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otS0t.png)

The problem is, after the first rotation in X also Z axis is rotated on X direction I must rotate not on the new normally Z but on the standard Z and when I translate I must move on standard axis non normally at final plane